# Convert GroupBy object to Dataframe (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am working with a large dataset which I've stored in a pandas dataframe. All of my methods I've written to operate on this dataset work on dataframes, but some of them don't work on GroupBy objects.

I've come to a point in my code where I would like to group all data by author name (which I was able to achieve easily via .groupby()). Unfortunately, this outputs a GroupBy object which isn't very useful to me when I want to use dataframe only methods.

I've searched tons of other posts but not found any satisfying answer... how do I convert this GroupBy object back into a DataFrame? (Note: It is much too large for me to manually select groups and concatenate them into a dataframe, I need something automated).

Comment: `for group_name, group in df.groupby(your_columns_here):` here group will give you a dataframe that u can pass to ur desired method

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan I didn't realize that group was a dataframe in that tuple output! That actually made my eventual usecase (counting up another column's value_counts within each group) much much easier to accomplish. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure I understand, so if this isn't what you are looking for, please comment.

Creating a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'author':['gatsby', 'king', 'michener', 'michener','king','king', 'tolkein', 'gatsby'], 'b':range(13,21)})

     author   b
0    gatsby  13
1      king  14
2  michener  15
3  michener  16
4      king  17
5      king  18
6   tolkein  19
7    gatsby  20

#create the groupby object
dfg = df.groupby('author')

In [44]: dfg
Out[44]: <pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x000002169D24DB20>

#show groupby works using count()
dfg.count()

          b
author
gatsby    2
king      3
michener  2
tolkein   1
```

But I think this is what you want. How to revert dfg back to a dataframe. You just need to perform some function on it that doesn't change the data. This is one way.

```
df_reverted = dfg.apply(lambda x: x)

     author   b
0    gatsby  13
1      king  14
2  michener  15
3  michener  16
4      king  17
5      king  18
6   tolkein  19
7    gatsby  20
```

This is another way and may be faster; note the dataframe names df and dfg.

```
df[dfg['b'].transform('count') > 0]
```

It's testing groupby and taking all groups greater than zero (so everything), returns a boolean series that is applied against the original dataframe, df

Comment: Hi Jonathan! While these both definitely work for reverting to a dataframe, my desired output is a dataframe which has been sorted by, for example, author name (into 'groups'). I have since realized that I was not approaching the problem the best way, and it was better to use a sort function on the original df['author'] column.